# C++ application crash after computing area

Tags: c++

I'm just curious why my application actually crashes after it compute the area of a cross.

I output is correct but it crashes after it calculation is done.

cross.cpp

```
void Cross::setCrossCord()
{
    for (int i=1; i<=12; i++)
    {
        cout << "Please enter x-ordinate of pt " << i << ": "; 
        cin >> xVal;
        xvalue[i] = xVal;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Please enter y-ordinate of pt " << i << ": ";
        cin >> yVal;
        yvalue[i] = yVal;
        cout << endl;
    }
}


double Cross::computeArea()
{
    int points = 12;
    int running_total = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<=12-1; i++)
    {
      running_total = (xvalue[i]*yvalue[i+1]) - (xvalue[i+1]*yvalue[i]);  //cross calculation of coord in a cross 
    }                                                                     //(x1*y2)-(y1*x1)

    running_total = (xvalue[points-1]*yvalue[0]) - (xvalue[0]*yvalue[points-1]);   // traverse back to the origin point
                                                                                   // (xn*y1)-(yn*x1)

    area = abs(running_total / 2); //purpose of absolute is to make sure result is positive. 
                                  //polygon are specified in counter-clockwise order (i.e. by the right-hand rule), then the area will be positive.

    cout << "area of cross is: " << area << endl;
    return (area);
}
int main()
{
    Cross cross;
    string shapetype;

    cout << "enter shape type: " << endl;
    cin >> shapetype;

    if(shapetype == "cross")
    {
    cross.setCrossCord();
    }else
    {cout << "error" << endl;};
    cross.computeArea();

}
```

this is the error I'm getting from windows, and I'm puzzled why this is happening.
[image: printscreen of error]

Comment: I'm guessing because you removed `return 0` from your main() method. Since it is still of type `int` it needs to return an integer value, even though it doesn't do anything valuable for you. Either change it to `void main()` or type `return 0` at the end of your code.

Comment: @NitroNbg please try another guess... You're completely wrong with that comment

Answer (score 2):

You must change the for loop in `setCrossCord` to be zero - based:

```
// change
for (int i=1; i<=12; i++)

// to
for (int i=0; i<12; i++)
```

Because arrays (and vectors etc.) are zerobased in C++

In fact you can see that this it the intended range because of the loop in `computeArea`.

The reason that the program crashes only after the computation is because out-of-bounds processing (specifically, writing) invoked *Undefined Behaviour*: it may crash or do random stuff: it's not error detection.

---

Here's a 'technically' fixed version of your code: **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fe612df4d0f9f1f2)**

However, you'd do good to (re)design your class to have only 1 responsibility (namely: represent a Cross, not do input or output. Also, the temporaries `xVal` and `yVal` should not live beyond the input procedure (and could be merged)).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Cross
{
    double xvalue[12], yvalue[12];

    void setCrossCord()
    {
        for (int i=0; i<12; i++)
        {
            cout << "Please enter x-ordinate of pt " << i << ": "; 
            double xVal, yVal;
            cin >> xVal;
            xvalue[i] = xVal;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Please enter y-ordinate of pt " << i << ": ";
            cin >> yVal;
            yvalue[i] = yVal;
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    double computeArea()
    {
        int points = 12;
        int running_total = 0;

        for (int i=0; i<12-1; i++)
        {
          running_total = (xvalue[i]*yvalue[i+1]) - (xvalue[i+1]*yvalue[i]);  //cross calculation of coord in a cross 
        }                                                                     //(x1*y2)-(y1*x1)

        running_total = (xvalue[points-1]*yvalue[0]) - (xvalue[0]*yvalue[points-1]);   // traverse back to the origin point
                                                                                       // (xn*y1)-(yn*x1)

        double area = abs(running_total / 2); //purpose of absolute is to make sure result is positive. 
                                      //polygon are specified in counter-clockwise order (i.e. by the right-hand rule), then the area will be positive.

        return (area);
    }

};
int main()
{
    Cross cross;
    string shapetype;

    cout << "enter shape type: " << endl;
    cin >> shapetype;

    if(shapetype == "cross")
    {
        cross.setCrossCord();
    }else
    {
        cout << "error" << endl;
    };

    cout << "area of cross is: " << cross.computeArea() << endl;
}
```

Comment: @TamilSelvan please don't approve random edits like that. ["Undefined Behaviour"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) is a very specific notion in C and C++ and should be capitalized to make this clear

Comment: @user2900611 Would you rather have a program that crashes, or a program that you can debug to fix the calculation?

Comment: please don't get the wrong idea.. i'm not rejecting any thing, but just curious why that happen.. sorry if i gave the wrong impression.

Comment: @MartinJames Ah, can you tell I'm on a windows with just Coliru a.t.m. :( Actually you just explained that funny `<=12 - 1` if you ask me

Answer (score 0):

I bet your indexing is wrong - C/C++ uses 0 based indexing, hence:

> for (int i=1; i<=12; i++)

and

> for (int i=0; i<=12-1; i++)

are fishy.
In addition index + 1 is.

Comment: I'm surprised that only you spotted the index+1's.

Answer (score 0):

1)your code
        cin>>yval;
        yvalue[i]=yval;
can be changed to
        cin>>yvalue[i];
2)arrays start from subscript 0 not 1
3)return something in main function(add return 0; statement in the end of main()) 
4)why are you returning any value from computearea() keep it void and don't return anything because you used the value in the function itself.
(i think point 3) causes the error but do correct all the four points in your code.

Comment: Your 3rd point is nonsense. `return 0` is implicit for the `main()` function.

Comment: implicit means if you not add still it gets added by itself?(don't know correctly 'cuz i am new to this C++ language and this world)

Comment: The `main` function is treated differently than other functions. If the `return` is omitted it's as if there is a `return 0` present.

Comment: that may be true for some compilers or editors but the compiler i use do give error when i forget to mention return 0 in main()

Comment: Your compiler might emit a diagnostic depending on the configured options but the ISO language standard is clear about a `main` without a return statement (section 3.6.1 para 5).

Comment: maybe the asker is using the type of compiler i am using and the compiler option is set to 'not to respond to errors'.